# Providers in lazy load modules

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

When I use lazy loading modules from Spartacus with service providers I get an error about the need to provide services:
app.module.ts:

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
  featureModules: {
    customCheckoutComponentModule: {
      module: () => import('@checkout/checkout.module').then((m) => m.CustomCheckoutComponentModule),
      cmsComponents: [
        'CheckoutOrderSummary',
        'CheckoutShippingDate'
      ],
    },
  },
})
```

Lazy module:

```
  @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CheckoutOrderSummaryModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: CustomCheckoutDeliveryAdapter,
      useClass: CustomOccCheckoutDeliveryAdapter,
    },
    {
      provide: CheckoutAdapter,
      useClass: CustomOccCheckoutAdapter,
    },
    {
      provide: PageMetaResolver,
      useExisting: CustomCheckoutPageMetaResolver,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class CustomCheckoutComponentModule {}
```

When I try to navigate to this lazy module, I get the following error:
[Error providers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vlll.png)

```
    errorhandler.js:33 Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CustomCheckoutComponentModule)[EffectsFeatureModule -> InjectionToken ngrx/effects: Feature Effects -> [object Object] -> PolygonsEffects -> CustomCheckoutDeliveryConnector -> CustomCheckoutDeliveryConnector -> CustomCheckoutDeliveryAdapter -> CustomCheckoutDeliveryAdapter -> CustomCheckoutDeliveryAdapter]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for CustomCheckoutDeliveryAdapter!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CustomCheckoutComponentModule)[EffectsFeatureModule -> InjectionToken ngrx/effects: Feature Effects -> [object Object] -> PolygonsEffects -> CustomCheckoutDeliveryConnector -> CustomCheckoutDeliveryConnector -> CustomCheckoutDeliveryAdapter -> CustomCheckoutDeliveryAdapter -> CustomCheckoutDeliveryAdapter]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for CustomCheckoutDeliveryAdapter!
```

This error occurs in only lazy module where providers exist

Lazy modules without providers do normal loading

I tried to move providers out of the lazy module, but failed

Comment: In order to isolate the issue, if you configure `CustomCheckoutComponentModule` to be normally loaded instead of lazy loaded, do you get the same errors?

Comment: There are no errors and everything works fine if lazy loading CustomCheckoutComponentModule is disabled

Comment: @shumakosik Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but perhaps it will be somewhat useful to somebody,

Have been experiencing a similar issues with mat-dialog and mat-select and after trying out everything, i decided to go for standalone components (Angular 14+) and it is been working great.